# Orientdb return RID when create vertex

Tags: orientdb, vertex, orientdb2.2, pyorient

my question is simple (I hope the answer is simple too) 
I want to return the RID when I create a vertex

```
client.command("create class Tag extends V") client.command("create vertex Tag set idTag=1, nomTag='tag1'")
```

Can I get the RID return?  or if I cannot can I create the vertex with a RID I chose? like:

```
client.command("create vertex Tag set rid='#21:1234', idTag=1, nomTag='tag1'")
```

-Using orientdb 2.2
-Pyorient (python API)
thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
just need to
RidReturn = client.command("create vertex Tag set idTag=1, nomTag='tag1'")

Rid = RidReturn[0]._rid

print(RidReturn)
```

[pyorient.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x107e00a90]

```
print(Rid)
```

'#27:3077'